# iMac is warming

Tags: macos, imac, temperature

I've 22 inch iMac. I am using it about 1 year and just noticed that the top back of the screen is very hot as i can't put my hand about half a minute on it.

I've googled some and downloaded istat Pro. Here are the temperatures of my system:

- HDD: 56 degree celcius
- CPU: 51 deg.cel.
- GPU Diode: 69 deg.cel.
- GPU Heatsink: 67deg.cel.
- Mem Controller: 57 deg.cel.
- Optical Drive: 50 deg.cel.
- Power supply: 59 deg.cel.

Are these values normal? or something going wrong with my computer?

By the way, i am not sure if there is any relationship but, i ve just upgraded to Mac OS X Lion. is it irrelevant or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **Those values are okay for a computer that is or has recently been under load.**

If you're getting these when it's just sitting idle, something may be wrong. However, if you're getting these while the computer is doing some work (or has recently done some work) these are reasonable. (I have a 22" iMac that I'm comparing yours to)

As for the top of the glass: The (one and only) fan vent is on the back of the computer near the top (where you're putting your hand). It's normal for that area to get very hot, as all the heat the computer generates passes through there. Mine gets hot after a while even if the computer hasn't been working hard.

If you're worried, you can check out the max temperature specs for your components. My iMac has [this processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/48505). As you can see under Package Specifications-> Tcase, the maximum temperature it can stand is 72.6* C, comfortably over your CPU's temperature (our models probably have similar maximum temperatures)